# symmetric function derived from a symmetric continuous pdf is positive definite?

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, density-function, positive-definite

Let $K(x)$ be a continuous bounded pdf symmetric about $0$; $K(x)$ is increasing for $x<0$ and decreasing for $x>0$. If $k(x,y):=K(x-y)$, then is $k(x,y)$ a positive definite function?

Comment: What do you mean by postive definite function $K(x)$ ? Perhaps $$\sum_{k,l=1}^nK(x_l-x_k)z_k\bar{z_l}\ge 0$$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Yes. Applying the definition for positive definite to $k(·,·)$ and it is exactly given by what you stated here, for all $z$'s, $x$'s, and for all $n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not necessarily. For kernels $K$ with integrable characteristic function, [Bochner's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_function#Bochner%27s_theorem) says that $K$ is positive definite if and only if its characteristic function is non-negative. If $K$ is the density of a sum of independent variables $U[-1, 1]$ and $N(0, 1)$, then it satisfies your conditions, but its characteristic function is

$$e^{-t^2/2}\frac{\sin(t)}{t},$$

which is integrable, and sometimes negative.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. However, the Bochner's theorem I found online only says if $\phi(t)$ is a continuous function with $\phi(0)=1$, then $\phi(·)$ is a characteristic function iff it's positive definite, which seems to be different from your version stated above. Do you have a reference that I can check? Thank you.

Comment: I've added a link. @NXWang

Comment: Perhaps I missed something, but I fail to see how we can deduce "the kernel $K$ is positive definite if and only if its characteristic function is non-negative" from Bochner's theorem.  I think the link you attached says basically the same thing as I commented above.

Comment: The link states that a continuous function $K$ is positive definite if and only if it's the Fourier transform of a non-negative measure, which is true if and only if its characteristic function is non-negative. @NXWang

Comment: Actually when I have a think again,  is the Fourier transform of a finite positive measure is equivalent to (let $K'(t) = K(t)/K(0)$) $K'(t)=\int e^{-itx} d\mu (x)$ for some probability measure , where this probability measure  may not have a density. Then how do we show that $\phi(x):= \int e^{itx} K'(t) dt$ (i.e. its characteristic function) is nonnegative  almost surely?

Comment: You have the wrong definition there; if $K$ is the Fourier transform of a measure $\mu$, then $K(t) = \int e^{-itx} d\mu(x)$, not $K'(t)$. (If you're not convinced, I'd suggest looking for further references; this is a very standard use of Bochner's theorem.) @NXWang

Comment: I agree with what you wrote here, but I was trying to express the Fourier transformation in terms of a probability measure (so that we have a characteristic function), which needs to ensure we divide by $K(0)$ I think.

Comment: I agree that the characteristic function $\phi(x)=\int e^{itx} K(t)dt$ satisfies $K(t)/(4\pi)=\int e^{-itx}\phi(x) dx$, but I think we still need to draw connection between $\mu$ and $\phi(x)$? I think the crucial property we want is the inversion rule (but as far as I understand, this can be a bit tricky when we only have a generic measure $\mu$ but not one with density).

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: the current (updated) answer by Adam (with the additional assumption that the characteristic function is integrable) fills in the gap and provides a simple solution.

---

**Outdated**: To supply @Adam's answer with more justification:

From Bachner's theorem, a function $K(·)$ is positive definite iff $K$ is the Fourier transform of a finite positive measure. By assumption, $K$ is a continuous pdf with $K(0)$ being the largest number, so $K(0)>0$ and $\tilde{K}(x):=\frac{K(x)}{K(0)}$ satisfies $\tilde{K}(0)=1$. Hence, one can show Bachner's theorem is equivalent to that $\tilde{K}(x)$ is the Fourier transform of some probability measure. By a change of variable, this is equivalent to $\tilde{K}(x)=\int e^{itx} d\mu(x)$ for some probability measure $\mu$, i.e. $\tilde{K}$ is a characteristic function.

Define $\phi(x):=\int e^{itx}K(t)dt$, which is a characteristic function derived from density $K$. We want to show if the above is true then the real part of $\phi(x)\geq 0$. Define $\tilde{\phi}(x):=\int e^{itx}\tilde{K}(t)dt$. Since $\phi(x)=K(0)\tilde{\phi}(x)$, it is equivalent to show $\tilde{\phi}(x)\geq 0$ (the key is to use the inversion formula given that $\tilde{K}$ is a characteristic function).

It is known that a characteristic function is bounded and continuous ($\phi$ is, hence so is $\tilde{\phi}$). Hence, if the real part of $\tilde{\phi}(x)<0$ at some $x\in R$, then there exists some neighborhood around $x$, say $(a,b)$, such that $(a,b)$ is a continuity set of $\mu$ (i.e. $\mu(\{a\}),\mu(\{b\}) = 0$; this holds since continuity points for probability measures on $R^n$ are dense), and satisfies the real part of $\int_a^b \tilde{\phi}(x) dx<0$. However,
$$\int_a^b \tilde{\phi}(x) dx = \int\frac{e^{itb}-e^{ita}}{it}\tilde{K}(t) dt = \int\frac{e^{-ita}-e^{-itb}}{it}\tilde{K}(t) dt \; \left(\text{let t=-t and use symmetry of}\, \tilde{K}\right)$$  $$= 2\pi \left[\frac{1}{2\pi} \lim_{T\rightarrow\infty} \int_{-T}^T\frac{e^{-ita}-e^{-itb}}{it}\tilde{K}(t) dt \right]$$

Since $\tilde{K}$ is a characteristic function derived from $\mu$ and $(a,b)$ is a continuity set for $\mu$, we can apply the inversion formula and get that the above expression equals $2\pi \mu((a,b])$, which then implies $\mu((a,b])<0$, which is a contradiction. Hence, $\tilde{K}(x)=\int e^{itx} d\mu(x)$ implies the real part of $\phi(x)\geq 0$.